Using the Instance on Points node, how can I capture or store the index of the point that the instance is created on?
How can I, given an input geometry to Instance on Points, get the index of each point that an instance is created on, for each instance? I want to use that index to sample an attribute from the source geometry, to use on each instance.

Just as you said, by capturing the index and sampling the attribute of the input geometry into a sample index node.

There, the index of the instances will be the index of the points.
Two options:

Capture attribute
Store named attribute

Just remember you're on an "instance domain".

